# Possible to assign one dropdown to multiple triggers?

Tags: jquery, angular, dropdown, semantic-ui

i'm wondering if it's possible to assign one dropdown to multiple triggers.
So i don't have to write alot of (the same) dropdowns in the page.

I have a table which loads dynamic content and if i hover the content i see a small button. I want to be able to open the dropdown if i click that button.

[image]

I got the styles so it show's like above but i need the logic behind it so it opens a dropdown (in semantic-ui or bootstrap)

Comment: little confused here ..what do you exactly need ?Just a menu dropdown on clicking the button ?

Comment: Yes, but since the buttons are loaded dynamically i don't want to have the dropdown code to be written alot of times.

Comment: can you paste the json response coming from the server so that i am clear about what you want

Comment: and paste what have tried so far.